# Week(Date) Function in Grails/Hibernate Criteria

Tags: hibernate, grails

i want to ask whether is it possible to get **week** number from date property of a domain with
**Grails or hibernate Criteria** ?

e.g in **mysql** it is `WEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130921/grails-gorm-select-as) question.

Answer (score 0):

you have to fetch the date property, convert the property and extract the week of year. e.g.

```
// fetch property from db
def test= Test.get(1)
// convert date and get week of year
println test.date.toCalendar().get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you can use Hibernate's `week()` function to do that provided your db support that.

For example, the following groups the entities (which is assumed to have a Date field with the name `dateEntered` by week and yields a `List<Object[]>` where for each `Object[]` in the list, the first element is the count, and the second element is the week number.

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.rowCount(), "parameterType")
                    .add(Projections.sqlGroupProjection(
                    "week({alias}.dateEntered) as week",
                    "week({alias}.dateEntered)",
                    new String[] {"week"},
                    new Type[] {Hibernate.INTEGER)))
                    .addOrder(Order.desc("parameterType"));
```