# Grails GORM : SELECT AS

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to get all the Users that are born today with GORM but I'm failing to write this query in Grails:

```
SELECT
DAY(dateOfBirth) AS 'day',
MONTH(dateOfBirth) AS 'month'
FROM Users
WHERE day = '...' AND month = '...';
```

`...` will be replaced with today's values.

**Minimal `User` Domain class**

```
class User {

  Date dateOfBirth

  ...

}
```

**Minimal `UserService` class**

```
@Transactional
class UserService {

  def getTodayBirthdays() {

    def bornTodayQuery = User.where{
      /* I'm thinking here I must
       * select the DAY and MONTH from the DB
       * and compare it with the today ones.
       */
    }       

    User usersBornToday = bornTodayQuery.findAll()      

    usersBornToday      

  }

}
```

Any ideas how can I do an alias (SELECT field AS alias) with GORM?

**I'm using:**

- Grails 2.4.4

**Thanks!**

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464500/gorm-equivalent-for-sql

Comment: @sebnukem Sort of, but I was looking for an approach that's not using `executeQuery`. That, of course, if it exists.

Comment: I don't think you can with GORM but I could be wrong...

Comment: @sebnukem Apparently you can, went with Beryllium's answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a **where query** in your service:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
def listBirthday(int _month, int _day) {
  // Calendar.JANUARY equals to zero!
  def m = _month + 1
  // Run a where query on the users
  User.where {
    month(dateOfBirth) == m && day(dateOfBirth) == _day
  }
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
def listBirthdayToday() {
  def cal = Calendar.getInstance()
  listBirthday(cal.get(cal.MONTH), cal.get(cal.DAY_OF_MONTH))
}
```

In addition to `month` and `day` there are some other functions, [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/single.html#whereQueries) is the documentation (look for "Other Functions")

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas how can I do an alias (SELECT field AS alias) with GORM?

```
(SELECT field AS _alias)
```

Putting an underscore (_) as prefix to alias worked for me with grails-2.5.6

I have not found it in documentation but using trail and error method.